# Better strategy than constructor injection or not?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

I am new to .NET Core, as far as I learned from Microsoft docs, we register services in `Startup.ConfigureServices` and inject them into classes through the constructors.

Something like the code below

**Startup**

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<ICar, Car>();
        services.AddScoped<IPeople, People>();
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```cs
public class CarController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ICar _car;
    private readonly IPeople _people;

    public CarController(ICar car, IPeople people)
    {
        _car = car;
        _people = people;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get()
    {
        var result = _people.Talk() + _car.Run();

        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

But one of my colleagues uses another strategy to achieve the injection, according to what he said, we could write less lines and the injection only happens when we invoke the properties.

(Sorry, I can't tell what is the name of this strategy.)

**Startup** (same as above)

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<ICar, Car>();
        services.AddScoped<IPeople, People>();
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```cs
public class CarController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    private ICar Car => _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ICar>();
    private IPeople People => _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IPeople>();

    public CarController(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get()
    {
        var result = People.Talk() + Car.Run();

        return Ok(result);
    }    
}
```

I am not sure is this correct or not.

Can someone point out the pros and cons between these two strategies?

Thank you.

Comment: That is called the service locator anit-pattern and it is usually debatable about whether it is good or bad. each camp has its own view about the merits and pitfalls of using it.

Comment: Microsoft docs usually advises against service locator anti-pattern and suggests using Explicit Dependency Principle via constructor injection.

Comment: You can learn more about the Service Locator anti-pattern in [this excerpt](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-service-locator-anti-pattern/) from [DIPP&P](https://manning.com/seemann2).

Comment: Thanks for providing the pattern name and the link, I'll do some research then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is way too close to a [service locator](https://proandroiddev.com/why-service-locator-is-so-unpopular-bbe8678be72c) , for which there are many (good) reasons not to use.

I can see some specific problems with the second solution. The first being that if the resource is registered as transient (`services.AddTransient<ICar, Car>();`), then each call of the property will return a new instance. This might be too surprising a behavior to expect from a property.

Next problem is a performance. Calling `GetRequiredService` is not free. And calling it each time a property is accessed might cause performance issues.

Both could be solved by getting the services in the constructor, like this :

```
private ICar Car;
private IPeople People;

public CarController(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    Car = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ICar>();
    People = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IPeople>();
}
```

But that still doesn't solve the problem of service locator, like it not being clear what dependencies a class is using and tying the class to the specific IoC provider. And really, you can save yourself the work and just declare the dependencies in the constructor at this point.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the example given by OP inside the `CarController` is a classic example of an implementation of the Service Locator pattern.